# What keywords are used by the Swedish analyzer?

Tags: elasticsearch

On [this part](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#swedish-analyzer) of the elasticsearch docs, it says that the Swedish analyzer can be reimplemented like this:

```
PUT /swedish_example
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "swedish_stop": {
          "type":       "stop",
          "stopwords":  "_swedish_" 
        },
        "swedish_keywords": {
          "type":       "keyword_marker",
          "keywords":   ["exempel"] 
        },
        "swedish_stemmer": {
          "type":       "stemmer",
          "language":   "swedish"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "swedish": {
          "tokenizer":  "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "swedish_stop",
            "swedish_keywords",
            "swedish_stemmer"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

My question is, how does this analyser recognise keywords? Sure, the keywords can be defined in the `settings.analysis.filter.swedish_keywords.keywords` field, but what if I'm too lazy to do that? Does Elasticsearch look at some other keywords list of pre-defined Swedish keywords? Because in the example above it looks like there is no such list provided in the settings.

In other words, is it solely up to me to define keywords or does Elasticsearch look at some other list to find keywords by default?

Comment: Yes, it is up to you. Do you need to define those keywords at all? In the docs they say: `This filter should be removed unless there are words which should be excluded from stemming.` Is it a problem that words will be stemmed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to specify this list by you. Otherwise, this filter wouldn't do **anything**.

As per documentation of Elasticsearch:

> Keyword Marker Token Filter
>
> Protects words from being modified by stemmers. Must be placed before
>   any stemming filters.

Alternatively, you could specify:

```
keywords_path
```

> A path (either relative to config location, or absolute) to a list of
>   words.

```
keywords_pattern
```

> A regular expression pattern to match against words in the text.

More information about this filter - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-marker-tokenfilter.html

Comment: So, that means that if I don't specify any keyword patterns, no words will be excluded from stemming? For example here:

`"settings":{
"mappings":{
    "motorcycle":{
        "properties":{
            "location": {
                "type":"text",
                "analyzer":"swedish"
            },
}
}`

Would this mean that no words are protected from stemming?

Comment: yes, it means no words protected from stemming, which makes no sense to have this filter in your settings